# CV score differs from test score

Tags: correlation, cross-validation

I have labelled data with 11 features. I am using CV within the training set to brute force the best subset of 11 features. I noticed that the CV scores for the top several subsets differ substantially from my test set scores. What are possible explanations / fixes?

Some information about my data.

- There are 144 data points in training, 108 in test
- I'm using a linear regression model to create predictions, but scoring predictions with spearman r
- This is human-labelled data with low agreement between humans (~0.35 correlation) so the golden standard is quite low
- There is a lot of variance among CV scores

Comment: So is your goal feature selection? Why are you using brute force for this? How are you using Spearman on the predictions?

Comment: My goal is to create a model that resembles human judgement. I'm using brute force because I've computed some features (each data point is a text source that is then ranked on a scale of 1-5 by humans) but I can't really tell which features correlate with human judgement. I use spearman to correlate my model's predictions with human labels, which I've seen in previous SemEval tasks

Comment: I don't understand. Can you edit your question with more details and context, what your data is, and what the goal is, rather than what you have tried.